# Update from origin to child branch after making some changes in origin

Tags: git, merge, bitbucket, git-pull

I created child branch from origin. I made some changes in child branch. There were some changes made in origin also. If I do git pull, it will override my changes. Now, how can I get changes from origin to child branch without effecting my changes.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that by "child branch" you mean a local branch that tracks the remote branch, and that the remote branch is the "origin" branch that has new changes, you can go ahead and do a `git pull` and your changes will not be overridden. Instead what will happen is that the changes made to the remote branch will be merged into your local branch, so you will have both your changes and the changes made to the remote branch.

Comment: thank you for confirmation.